# Laravel 5.3 @extends('layouts.app') return Trying to get property of non-object error

Tags: laravel-5.3

I  am a newbie in laravel. I got this error in my page

```
  ErrorException in 8afd74a6e1e33743517baf7fe73821f647ea6aa5.php line 69: Trying to get property of non-object (View: /home/vagrant/sites/ocean/resources/views/layouts/app.blade.php) (View: /home/vagrant/sites/ocean/resources/views/layouts/app.blade.php)
```

index.blade.php file :

```
@extends('layouts.app')
```

StudentsController :

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class StudentsController extends Controller
{
    public function index()
    {
        return view('students.index');

    }
}
```

Comment: is `@extends('layouts.app')` all you have in your `index.blade.php`???

Comment: Yes, I just want to try to use master layout.  But it returned that error.

Comment: Can you please share your views/layouts/app.blade.php? –

Answer (score 0):

I face the same problem in Laravel 5.4, searched alot but didn't find any solution and the i made new layout and then extend it and it worked.

`@extends('layouts.newapp')`